# Use Angular Id value from ng-reapt in a razor @Url.Action link

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass values to my controller action from link in View:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(DetailsViewModel vm)
{
    if (vm.CarId == 0 || vm.Email == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Error");
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Model:

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }   
}
```

The problem is that CarId is a an Angular value being displayed via binding in an ng-repeat - e.g. `{{item.id}}`

Therefore, how do I get the CarID in Link?

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Cars", new { @CarID = ??, @Email = ViewBag.Email })" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Book Car Now</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe since angular will be compiled after the Url.Action call is rendered by the server, you will not be able to pass in client side information to the Url.Action call. Will this work for your solution:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Cars")?CarId={{item.Id}}&Email=@ViewBag.Email" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Book Car Now</a>
```